# Angular 2 - Kendo UI Grid - Paging listed vertically, not horizontally

Tags: angular

I am using the new Angular 2 Kendo UI Grid, everything works great except for the paging diplay - if there are 10 pages in my grid the numbers 1 through 10 are listed vertically under the grid instead of in a horizontal line.   Any suggestions for correcting this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Comment: Fixed it myself: the issue was the Telerik style sheet needed to be referenced in the styles section of the angular-cli.json